# Get wrong address on Outlook public places suggestions corrected

Tags: microsoft-outlook, geolocation, bing-maps

When typing the location for an Outlook event, it suggests public places in a dropdown. However, the address is sometimes wrong such as this one which shows postcode 2661 RT:

[image: Screenshot of new Outlook event showing location suggestions]

It should be 2661 RW. However, the [same address on Bing Maps](https://www.bing.com/maps?&cp=51.996708%7E4.501988&lvl=16&osid=9f3bd143-9542-4db2-b590-73e72636ac58&v=2&sV=2&form=S00027) shows the correct postcode.

According to [here](https://office365itpros.com/2019/08/28/outlook-places-service/), Outlook creates suggested locations using the [Bing Maps Locations API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/locations/). If that is true, then there seems to be a discrepancy between Bing Maps and this API, so it doesn't make sense to use the feedback widget in the former if it is correct there.

My question is, is it correct that Outlook public place suggestions are obtained from the Bing Maps Locations API; and in any case, how can I get this corrected?

Comment: "how can I get this corrected?" Not here. Report to Bing (which is owned by Microsoft)

Comment: Type the correct full address, next time you need to use that address, the correct address (on the same machine and account) will make the correct suggestion

Comment: @DavidPostill Unhelpful. And this is about computer software, so you should not have closed this question. Reporting to Bing is not an option for the reason clearly stated in the question.

Comment: @Ramhound That doesn't work unfortunately. I already tried that. The correct address is not stored as a public place. If I type it in in full, obviously that works, but that defeats the purpose of using the feature.

Comment: @Neo - If my suggestion does not work then must report the error to Bing Maps.

Comment: @Neo It is about an error in software which can only be fixed by the vendor. So it is off topic.

Comment: @DavidPostill All errors in all closed source software can only be fixed by the vendor. OSS errors would be more appropriate in SO. So, your logic would suggest that any topics about software errors in SU are off-topic, which is ludicrous as the tagline for SU is that it "is a question and answer site for computer enthusiasts and power users." In this case, I fall into that category, and have a question about a feature. An answer on how to correct it would be appropriate. You have assumed that the answer is to contact Microsoft, and this might not be the answer. That's not for you to decide.

Comment: @Ramhound Well, so far I've contacted them in 3 ways. 1) As described [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/maps/report-bug) (using the Feedback button on [Bing Maps](https://www.bing.com/maps) itself). 2) Via [Microsoft Support for Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook). 3) Via the application itself as per [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-do-you-report-an-issue-or-bug-a318252f-cc24-4e95-bec9-71bd2dbc379d). Let's see where these get me.

Comment: From Microsoft Support... _"Kindly note that this is a known issue that we are currently working to correct as soon as possible. Some users have been able to notice and report that. However, the location you see on outlook is not meant to show locations outside of contacts saved on the outlook app. That is why the locations of real places it shows are not always correct. No worries, future updates would be able to handle that just in case users would like to utilize that option."_

Comment: You should post the answer from Microsoft support as an answer and accept it since it is authoritative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested [in response](https://superuser.com/questions/1735581/get-wrong-address-on-outlook-public-places-suggestions-corrected#comment2687902_1735581) to my comment [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1735581/get-wrong-address-on-outlook-public-places-suggestions-corrected#comment2687321_1735581), this is the answer I received from Microsoft Support...

> Kindly note that this is a known issue that we are currently working to correct as soon as possible. Some users have been able to notice and report that. However, the location you see on outlook is not meant to show locations outside of contacts saved on the outlook app. That is why the locations of real places it shows are not always correct. No worries, future updates would be able to handle that just in case users would like to utilize that option.

This seems definitive and authoritative, and therefore answers my question.